# Limit is not working with GAE Search API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

### My Code:

```
  SortExpression sortExpr = SortExpression.newBuilder()
    .setExpression(locExpr)
    .setDirection(SortExpression.SortDirection.ASCENDING)
    .setDefaultValueNumeric(distanceInMeters + 1)
    .build();

Query searchQuery = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(QueryOptions.newBuilder()
    .setSortOptions(SortOptions.newBuilder().addSortExpression(sortExpr))
    .setLimit(10)) // this limit is not working, Problematic line
    .build(query);

Results<ScoredDocument> results = getIndex().search(searchQuery);
```

1) It is returning 1020  records instead of 10 (as I set in Limit). What's wrong in the above code?

2) If I remove limit condition **it returns 1020 records instead 2000(i.e all records)**, why it's not returning all 2000 records? Is there any fetching limit of Search API?

Answer (score 0):

That looks right to me.  Please file a bug report on the external issue tracker, and we will investigate.